# Custom FXML component (w/ controller) doesn't appear in SceneBuilder's "Import jar" dialog

Tags: java, javafx, custom-controls, fxml

I am following [this](https://rterp.wordpress.com/2014/07/28/adding-custom-javafx-component-to-scene-builder-2-0-part-2/) in creating a custom component and importing it. However, when it gets to the Import Dialog after clicking the jar file, it does not appear. When I comment out the code the tutorial used for the constructor, it appears again. However, none of the subcomponents I used to make the custom one appear. Why and how do I fix it?

Also, I am using a VBox instead of an AnchorPane (as seen in the tutorial) for my own thing.

Code of constructor as seen in tutorial:

```
public CommodityImageLabel() {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(
            getClass().getResource("/fxml/CommodityImageLabel.fxml"));

    fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);

    try {
        fxmlLoader.load();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }

}
```

Code for my own example's constructor:

```
public While() {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(
            getClass().getResource("BlocksFXML/While.fxml"));


    fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);

    try {
        fxmlLoader.load();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
}
```

Edit1: I tried commenting out parts of the code, and when I comment out the try-catch part, it makes the component appear in the dialog, but it still doesn't show the subcomponents.

Edit 2: The custom component is basically a VBox containing an Hbox with a Label and a TextField. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0TZ2.jpg) is what it's supposed to look like vs what ends up looking like when it successfully imports without the try-catch part.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include an example of code that doesn't appear?

Comment: @James_D I'm not sure what you mean, because FXML is complete, but the component doesn't show up like it's supposed to when I import it to SceneBuilder. I included pictures, if they're helpful.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. Are you saying the version in the tutorial doesn't work? I thought only your own example didn't work. Which Scene Builder version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, my own example is the one not working. I recently installed Scene Builder on this laptop so I'm guessing it's the latest one.

Comment: If your own example is the one not working, it's not really going to be any help to post a snippet of the example that *does* work. Create the simplest example you can that *doesn't* work, and edit your question to include it. Which version number does your installation of Scene Builder have?

Comment: Sorry for being a noob D: I added the code for the constructor for my own now, but it's almost the same as the one in the example except for names. I have Scene Builder 2.0, I think.

Comment: See if upgrading to the [latest version](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/) helps

Comment: Oh no. I'm using JavaFX Scene Builder and not Gluon. Whoops.

Comment: Same product, but Gluon took over development from Oracle after version 2.

Comment: Interesting info James_D thanks for that!

Comment: Did you solve this? I was following the same process and have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using the information here:

http://www.cuchazinteractive.com/blog/custom-javafx-controls-and-scene-builder

To summarise:

1. Create an FXML file and a Java class that extends the root node (I gave them the same name)
2. Change the FXML file to have `fx:root` as the base node. (will not work without this)
3. Remove the `fx:controller` attribute (will not work without this)
4. Compile and add the jar to scene builder

However, I have found that if your custom control depends on controls from other libraries, it will fail even if the other library is loaded in scene builder.

Below is a minimum working example

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<fx:root id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="73.0" prefWidth="112.0" type="AnchorPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="25.0" layoutY="28.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

Java:

```
package my.amazing.controls;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class TestControl extends AnchorPane {


    public TestControl() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("TestControl.fxml"));
        loader.setRoot(this);
        loader.setController(this);
        loader.load();
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
    }
}
```