# Importing a Custom Component in to Scene builder

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, jfoenix

There are many similar questions but i am not sure what i am doing wrong,

below are my two classes,

**class 1:**

```
public class CustomTreeTableViewColumn extends JFXTreeTableColumn {

    public CustomTreeTableViewColumn() {
        super();
    }

    public CustomTreeTableViewColumn(String text) {
        super(text);
    }
}
```

**class 2:**

```
public class CustomTreeTableView extends JFXTreeTableView {

    public CustomTreeTableView() {
        super();
    }
}
```

**JFoenix version** : 9.0.8
**JDK Version** : 11
**Scene Builder** : Gluon 10.0.0

When i try to import above classes as jar in scene builder i see no UI components.

So i tried this following example,

[SceneBuilder - Add custom component which relies on third party components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54006482/scenebuilder-add-custom-component-which-relies-on-third-party-components)

[Custom FXML component (w/ controller) doesn't appear in SceneBuilder's "Import jar" dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429456/custom-fxml-component-w-controller-doesnt-appear-in-scenebuilders-import-j)

but nothing seems to work.

How can i import these custom components in Scene builder?

Comment: Have you imported JFoenix into Scene Builder library of custom controls?

Comment: Also, for Java 11 you should use Scene Builder 11

Comment: @JoséPereda i have imported JFoenix, i will try with Scene Builder 11 ..

Comment: @JoséPereda Thanks i am able to import `class 2` now, but still class 1 is not available.. Even If i import `jfoenix jar` , i am not able to see `JFXTreeTableColumn`

Comment: Yes, because it is not a control (it doesn't extend from `Node`), you won't be able to see it.

Comment: @JoséPereda `JFXTreeTableColumn` extends `TreeTableColumn` , but in scene builder we are able to see `TreeTableColumn` even though it doesn't extends from `Control`. What is happening there ?

Comment: There is built-in support in Scene Builder for it. Otherwise you couldn't deal with components like Tab`, `TableColumn`, ... But that can't be provided for custom components out of the box.